# Glew initialisation failed : Missing GL version (GLFW)

Tags: c++, opengl, glfw, glew

I'm currently trying to draw a simple triangle with GLFW and GLEW.

I'm using CLion (which is itself using cmake with cygwin) on a Win 8.1 x64 PC.

My problem is : `glewInit()` returns error 1 (`Missing GL version`) when initialized. People (like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276444/failed-to-initialize-glew-missing-gl-version) thread) had a problem related to the OpenGL context, but mine is already created before I call `glewInit()`.

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <vector>

#define GLEW_STATIC

#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <glm/glm.hpp>

//...

if(!glfwInit()) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't initialize GLFW" << std::endl;
}

glfwSetErrorCallback(glfw_error_callback);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4); //16x antialiasing sisi rpz
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3); // OpenGL 3.3
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

window = glfwCreateWindow(width, height, title.c_str(), NULL, NULL);
if(window == NULL) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to open GLFW window. Are your drivers up-to-date ?" << std::endl;
    glfwTerminate();

    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
if(!glfwGetCurrentContext()) {
    std::cerr << "Couldn't create OpenGL context" << std::endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
GLenum err = glewInit();
if(err != GLEW_OK) {
    std::cerr << "Failed to initialize glew : " << glewGetErrorString(err) << " (" << err << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

and my CMakeLists.txt :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.4)
project(MY_PROJECT)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp Host.cpp GraphicWindow.cpp)
add_executable(MY_PROJECT ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(MY_PROJECT wsock32 ws2_32)

#GL stuff
include_directories(lib/glew-1.11.0/include/)
include_directories(lib/glfw-3.0.4.bin.WIN64/include/)
include_directories(lib/glm)

target_link_libraries(MY_PROJECT glfw3 glu32 gdi32 opengl32 glew)
```

Comment: What's you hardware and driver versions?Try to init with 3.2.GL3.3 won't work with old or onboard video cards.

Comment: My video card is a GTX 660, latest drivers, supporting OpenGL > 4.

It looks like GLEW is unable to fetch the GL version from the glfw context ? But when I call `glGetString(GL_VERSION)`, it works well (but I'm uanble to use `glGenBuffers()` because glew doesn't work).