# Qt QOpenGLWidget crash when call glewInit() with error : Missing GL version

Tags: qt, opengl, 3d, glew, qopenglwidget

I use Qt to create a 3D program with GLEW.
I have a problem when I call *glewInit*() from run-time creating Widget.
I create an inherited class , **MyRender**, based on **QOpenGLWidget**. Then, implemented *initializeGL*() with

```
GLenum err;
if( err = glewInit() )
{
    printf( "error because: %s\n", glewGetErrorString( err )  );
    exit(123);
}
```

Normally, I use class **MyRender** via Qt Designer and promote **QOpenGLWidget** to **MyRender**. Then I will have **MyRender** Object since the program starts. There is no problem.

However, when I create **MyRender** at Run-time. For example;

```
MyRender * myrender = new MyRender ( this );
```

The program will crash when calling *glewInit()*

```
Missing GL version   // glewInit() problem
```

I found the people who have the same problem as me from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14276444/failed-to-initialize-glew-missing-gl-version)

However, in the post, people use either GLUT or SDL to create context. Since I use only GLEW how could I make the context from **QOpenglWidget** the same way as

```
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGB); //use GLUT
```

or

```
sf::Window   App(sf::VideoMode(400, 400, 32), "Window"); //use SDL
```

or

```
glfwMakeContextCurrent    // use glfw
```

Since I use none of them. I use only QOpenGLWidget and glew. I tried with

```
myrender->makeCurrent(); // fail
myrender->initializeGL(); // fail
```

before calling

```
glewInit()
```

however, the problem still persists.

About my machine: I use Windows 10 64-bit. Qt 5.11 GLEW 2.1.0

EDIT:

I test my code with

```
 void initializeGL()
 {
        echo("inside initializeGL");

        QOpenGLContext* current = this->context();
        if( current == nullptr )
        {
            printf("current context is null\n");
            exit(123);
        }
        else
        {
           printf("current context is good\n");
        }

        GLenum err = glewInit();  // error here
        ...
 }
```

If I use Qt Designer to promote openGLWidget to **MyRender** . the *context* will be OK;
However, if I create **MyRender** in Run-time

```
MyRender* myrender = new MyRender( this );
```

The context will be null and leads *glewInit*() error.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem is context is not created, and when the program call function *initializeGL*(). The solution that I did is I call *show()*; right after creating the widget.

```
myrender = new MyRender( ui->mdiArea );
myrender->show(); // this line make the context for QOpenGLWidget I think..

... 
// note class MyRender is an inherited class from QOpenGLWidget
```